# Prove intersection of all inductive sets is inductive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that the intersection of all inductive sets is inductive?

Subset A of ordered field F is inductive, when:

1) $1 \in A$

2) if $a \in A$ then $a+1 \in A$

Prove that $$\mathbb{I} = \bigcap \left\{A\in F\ {\large|} \ A \text{ is inductive }\right\}$$ is inductive.

Answer (score 3):

First prove if $1\in\mathbb I$.

Second prove that if $a\in\mathbb I$ then $a+1\in\mathbb I$.

Use definition that $x\in\mathbb I=\bigcap\limits_{A\in F_{\text{ind}}}A\iff \forall A\in F_{\text{ind}},x\in A$.  Where $F_{\text{ind}}$ is the collection of all inductive sets.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Recall that $x\in\bigcap\cal A$ if and only if for every $A\in\cal A$, $x\in A$.